# Transformar RowDataPacket em objeto para criar sessão de login

Tags: javascript, node.js, session

Bom dia.

Estou fazendo uma aplicação node.js que ao fazer login deve salvar os atributos do usuário (atributos do banco de dados, como nome, sobrenome, email, id, etc). Mas ao mandar exibir na tela, não informa erros mas também nem o nome do usuário.
Estou utilizando "express-session" e "cookie-parser".

No query da busca, caso encontrado e compatíveis usuário e senha:

```
req.session.usuario = results; //criando sessao do usuario
res.redirect('/'); //redireciona para index agora logado
```

Fiz um teste para ver se **results** estava pegando os dados certos com um console.dir e está tudo ok, recupera os atributos do usuário em um vetor no índice do nome no banco e valor recuperado(nome: x, sobrenome: y]

No **app.js** da aplicação, há uma função app.use para instanciar a sessão:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
   res.locals.session  = req.session.usuario; //para exibir o nome do usuario na tela [partials - menu]
   console.dir("res.locals.session>>> "+res.locals.session);
   console.dir("req.session.usuario>>> "+req.session.usuario);
   res.locals.isLogged = req.session.usuario ? true : false; //se usuario logado = true, se nao = false [layout] 
   next();
});
```

Utilizei os consoles.dir para tentar ver como estão os itens dentro do **res.locals.session e req.session.usuario**, mas em ambos apenas retorna **[object Object]**

Meu intuito é recuperar o id e o nome do usuário para

**1º - Exibir o nome do usuário no menu:**

```
if isLogged 
    li 
        a(id="tamanhoLinkMenu" href="/logout") Ola, #{session.nome} Logout
```

ps.: O *isLogged* funciona perfeitamente, pois quando o usuário está logado aparece "Olá, Logout", mas notem que não aparece o nome do usuário

**2º - Recuperar o id para exibir ao usuário apenas os produtos que lhe pertencem**

Se alguém souber o que estou fazendo de incorreto e puder ajudar ou dar um caminho a seguir, agradeço.

Grande abraço.

---

editado:
Amigos, consegui alguma solução para o meu problema.

**Acontece que eu estou utilizando o banco MySQL e estava seguindo um exemplo de um sistema que utilizava MongoDB.**

O MySQL retorna um **array** com os resultados e para criar uma **sessão do usuário** aparentemente precisa de um **objeto** para poder ser instanciada.

```
 Retorno MySQL visto no console:

 [RowDataPacket {
   id: 1,
   nome: x,
   sobrenome: y
} ]
```

Para, portanto, salvar os dados que preciso na sessão, é necessário converter esse array[] para um objeto{}. Infelizmente não consegui faze-lo a mão. Tentei utilizar uma função, algumas conversões para JSON, mas nenhuma ficou apenas em objeto {} com os índices e valores.

Fiz um pequeno objeto na mão e salvei apenas os itens que preciso de imediato:
ps.: Como a consulta SQL deve retornar apenas 1 usuário, sei que o mesmo é o índice [0] dos resultados

```
UsuarioDados = {
   _id: results[0].usuario_id,
   nome: results[0].nome,
   sobrenome: results[0].sobrenome
}
```

E salvo a sessão com:

```
 req.session.usuario = UsuarioDados;
```

Agora talvez a pergunta mude um pouco: Alguém sabe como converter o Array **[RowDataPacket{indice: valor, indice: valor}]** em um objeto apenas **{indice: valor, indice: valor}** de uma maneira que funcione, retirando a inscrição RowDataPacket?

Comment: Pelos seus exemplos o `RowDataPacket` já é um objeto no formato `{chave:valor}`. Substitua a linha: `req.session.usuario = UsuarioDados;` por `req.session.usuario = results[0];`.

Comment: Perfeito PanterA! Muitíssimo obrigado!